# Creating an object with no existing class

Tags: java, class, parsing

I would like to know if it is possible to create a "temporary" object (at runtime) of a class that does not exist, and create fields for that object.

I'm parsing a text file for which I would need to create manually hundreds, if not more, of classes to store (and later write) all the data represented in this file.

That file would look like :

```
person,John,28,USA,Male
person,Rebecca,25,USA,Female
```

... later ...

```
address,John,...
address,Rebecca,..
```

I would like to make a method that will, when metting a new kind of data (here, a Person or an Address), create an object of the corresponding class (Person.class or Address.class), class that doesn't exist in my src code.

Then, I'll split the line around (",") and for each String, create a new Field for that new Object and put the value inside.

EDIT :

Found [dexmaker](http://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/) that seems to be what I need, but will I be able to use the dexmaker generated class to build an output xml using JAXB/DOM or other similar implementations ?

Thanks

Comment: check out cglib. but the biggest question would be - why do you need that?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? why not model the data you want to read upfront, create the domain classes and then construct them from the files?

Comment: how is the program supposed to know that the data represents a new class?

Comment: @MarcoForberg The file I'm parsing is an sql file exported, so values respect a precise order

Comment: @AkshaySinghal Because that file is a 120MB long, representing hunderds of differents objects (like person or address) that I'll have to write (after my parsing) in hundreds of different xml files.
So I'd like to avoid writing all those classes

Comment: Why not store in DOM objects right away then? Also, DBUnit can export data tables to xml for you.

Comment: @Viria: but if you know the "data types" before, why not create the classes before your run your import?

Comment: You might be interested in [this related answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453155/dynamically-editing-creating-classes-in-java-android/7453490#7453490).

Comment: @Viria sorry, but this does not seem like a good solution to pursue at all. If you hell bent against modelling your data into classes, just use loads of Maps, don't look for a way to create objects without classes.

Comment: @MarcoForberg I'd like to avoid writing manually so many classes, the goal of that method would be creating classes automatically, naming fiels according to the "keys" of the sql data structure.

I.E. :
CREATE TABLE "person" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL, "age" integer NOT NULL ...

-> Class Person, with fields Name (String) and Age (Integer)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `HashMap<String, String>` as your flexible object: every key (fieldname) refers to a field value.

For every type (Address, Person) add a HashMap, and for keeping trac of the type-hashmaps, well use a `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>` :)

This works a bit like javascript objects which are in effect associative arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can have any class which holds String key and values in a Properties container. Not sure why is usefully...

For SQL there are ORM frameworks, which will do your job automatically, if you have linked the library and configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need temporary object ? If you really do not want to create any class in source code then , you can take a help of Collections.Use a suitable collection for keeping the data for short period of time.

They are predefined , no need to create any class for that.You can use HashMap,HashTable,etc.

Answer (score 0):

For storing parsing data, you can use Collections class utilities. I am also working on parsing files, i always prefer to use Map,List. Java provides these things for fast development, no time wasting. Create an object for every new data and compare these objects for storing only different typs of objects in Map..